# Does deleting an AutoML Vision dataset also delete the model?

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I'm creating models in Google's AutoML Vision Image Classification service. When deploying new models, I want to delete their predecessors.

In the console, deleting the trained model does not delete the dataset. However, deleting the dataset appears to delete the model. When deleting a model, the following warning is shown: `Your model will be removed from Google Cloud, and any API queries to this model will no longer work.` When deleting a dataset, this warning is shown: `Your dataset will be removed from Google Cloud, including all label data. Your images on Cloud Storage (GCS) will not be affected.`. Again, there is no indication that deleting the dataset also deletes the model. It makes sense that it appeared to have done so when I tested it, given how the dataset and model are tied together in the console, but I cannot find any documentation regarding this.

When using the client APIs, such as NodeJS, the documentation shows both [how to delete a dataset](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/automl/latest/v1beta1.AutoMlClient.html#deleteDataset) and [how to delete a model](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/automl/latest/v1beta1.AutoMlClient.html#deleteModel). However, there does not seem to be any indication of whether or not deleting the dataset also deletes the model.

Google's docs on [managing datasets](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/datasets) and [managing models](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/models) also do not specify whether or not deleting the dataset also deletes the model.

**When using the client APIs, do I only have to delete the dataset, or do I have to both delete the dataset and the model?**

I'm inclined to believe that the model does get deleted with the dataset- but I'd like to make sure that this is truly the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: This answer was made with the `v1beta1` API, before the release of the `v1` API. I believe this answer is no longer true with the `v1` API.**

I've now tested this with the NodeJS client library and can confirm that the `deleteDataset` method does delete both the dataset and its corresponding model.

```
const formattedParent = automl.locationPath('foobar', 'us-central1');

// List Datasets
const datasetsA = await automl.listDatasets({parent: formattedParent})
console.log(`BEFORE Datasets: ${JSON.stringify(datasetsA, null, 4)}`)

// List Models
const modelsA = await automl.listModels({parent: formattedParent})
console.log(`BEFORE Models: ${JSON.stringify(modelsA, null, 4)}`)

// Delete Dataset
const formattedName = automl.datasetPath('foobar', 'us-central1', 'barbaz')
const [operation, initialApiResponse] = await automl.deleteDataset({name: formattedName})
const responses = await operation.promise()
const result = responses[0]
const metadata = responses[1]
const finalApiResponse = responses[2]
console.log(`result: ${JSON.stringify(result, null, 4)}`)
console.log(`metadata: ${JSON.stringify(metadata, null, 4)}`)
console.log(`finalApiResponse: ${JSON.stringify(finalApiResponse, null, 4)}`)

// List Datasets
const datasetsB = await automl.listDatasets({parent: formattedParent})
console.log(`AFTER Datasets: ${JSON.stringify(datasetsB, null, 4)}`)

// List Models
const modelsB = await automl.listModels({parent: formattedParent})
console.log(`AFTER Models: ${JSON.stringify(modelsB, null, 4)}`)
```

The output to console confirms that the model no longer exists after the delete LRO completes.